# How can I check to see if anyone has tried to file my tax return

Tags: united-states, taxes, identity-theft

How can I check to see if anyone has tried to file my tax return? I have reason to suspect that someone has stolen my social security number.

Comment: I don't really see a question in there. Could you explain what your concerns are and what specifically you need help with?

Comment: Assuming this is in the USA, you can get an IRS summary of your taxes and reported income for the past several years for free from the IRS website.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest calling the IRS and explaining your situation. Very likely, someone answering the phones there has heard this exact question a few times and will know where to direct you.

I was initially inclined to suggest using the IRS' "Where's My Refund?" tool, but it requires that you know approximately the date/time you submitted the refund, as well as the approximate dollar amount of the return value.